# How do I declare the arguments and a return type for a private class member in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am attempting to convert some code from vanilla javascript, and part of that requires storing a function as a private class member. I am attempting to figure out the proper syntax for this, but can't seem to get it right.

What I want to ultimately say is:

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClass {
        private myLocalReferenceToTheFunction: Function<T>(serverCall: (...args: any[]) => ng.IPromise<T>): ng.IPromise<T>;

        constructor(myOtherService: OtherService) {
           this.myLocalReferenceToTheFunction = myOtherService.serviceFunction;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the proper syntax for the `private myLocalReferenceToTheFunction...` line?

Tangentially, if this is the totally wrong way to go about doing this, I'd appreciate knowing. Really, my only end goal is to be able to use `myLocalReferenceToTheFunction` in functions inside of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like this is what you're trying to do:

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClass<T> {
        private myLocalReferenceToTheFunction: (serverCall: (...args: any[]) => ng.IPromise<T>) => ng.IPromise<T>;

        constructor(myOtherService: OtherService) {
            this.myLocalReferenceToTheFunction = myOtherService.serviceFunction;
        }
    }
}
```

Hard for me to tell for sure that this is what you need though.
Seeing the definition of `OtherService` would help.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I was trying to do, except it was: `        private myLocalReferenceToTheFunction: <T>(serverCall: (...args: any[]) => ng.IPromise<T>) => ng.IPromise<T>;`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var MyModule = function() {
    return {
        MyClass : function () {
            var myLocalReferenceToTheFunction;
            var constructor = function(myOtherService) {
                myLocalReferenceToTheFunction = myOtherService;
            };
            return constructor;
        }()
    };
}();
```

Comment: That looks like the vanilla JS I'm trying to get generated, but I'd like to be able to compile this with typescript.

Comment: Not great with typescript. Try this:
    module MyModule {
        class MyClass {
            var myLocalReferenceToTheFunction;
            constructor(public myOtherService) {
                this.myLocalReferenceToTheFunction = myOtherService;
            }
        }
    }